# xkbcomp complains about syntax error in xkb_keycodes section

Tags: x11, xkb

In a start to understand xkb as a preparation to create my own personal keyboard layout, I created an xkb config file. This is (a representative part of the start of**strong text**) my X keyboard configuration file:

```
xkb_keymap {
        xkb_keycodes "de|ru" {
                minimum = 8;
                maximum = 255;

[...]
                <F11>         =  95; // <FK11>
                <F12>         =  96; // <FK12>
//              <SYSRQ>       = 107; // <PRSC>
//              <SCROLL_LOCK> =  78; // <SCLK>
//              <PAUSE>       = 127; // <PAUS>

//              <CIRCUMFLEX>  =  49; // <HZTG>, <TLDE>
                <1>           =  10; // <AE01>
                <2>           =  11; // <AE02>
[...]
```

Now, I try to actually use it on my secondary keyboard, but when running the command `xkbcomp -i 12 $FILE $DISPLAY` I get this errors:

```
syntax error: line $LINE of $FILE
last scanned symbol is: $SYMBOL
Errors encountered in $FILE; not compiled.
```

With SYMBOL being any of SYSRQ, SCROLL_LOCK, PAUSE or CIRCUMFLEX (the list goes on later in unpasted parts). When I comment out those lines like shown here, xkbcomp just fails on later problems of the same kind. So why do I get a syntax error on SYSRQ but not on ESC or F12? The lines all are syntactically identical. Are there any reserved names? Or are the names I can use actually predetermined? Where can I find any useful documentation on this? (I already consulted the manpages and Google, came up with incomplete and contradictionary tutorials with don't even reveal any idea why I could get this kind of errors.)

Comment: Have you tried `ckbcomp`? I found it via `apropos xkb` ... It seems to be related to the lot, in particular to `setxkbmap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest to a description I have is from [The X Keyboard Extension: Protocol Specification](https://www.x.org/archive//current/doc/kbproto/xkbproto.html):

> Each key has a **four-byte symbolic name**. The key name links keys with
> similar functions or in similar positions on keyboards that report
> different scan codes. Key aliases allow the keyboard layout designer to
> assign multiple names to a single key, to make it easier to refer to keys
> using either their position or their "function."

The names are often just positions, like `<AB02>` meaning row B key 2 from the bottom left, as in the picture in [An Unreliable Guide to XKB Configuration](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/index.html) section [Key Codes](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/html/node3.html#SECTION00033000000000000000) ([PDF version](https://www.charvolant.org/doug/xkb/xkb.pdf)).